# why test ads not showing in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, ads, flutter-test

Test ads was working fine but now test ads are not showing i am getting this.

```
I/Ads     (10681): This request is sent from a test device.
W/ConnectionStatusConfig(10681): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: 
com.google.android.gms.ads.service.CACHE
W/ConnectionStatusConfig(10681): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: 
com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START
I/Ads     (10681): This request is sent from a test device.
I/AdCheck (10681): APS: blockAdView! 
I/Ads     (10681): This request is sent from a test device.
W/Ads     (10681): Not retrying to fetch app settings
W/Ads     (10681): Not retrying to fetch app settings
I/DynamiteModule(10681): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and 
remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:224400003
I/DynamiteModule(10681): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, 
version >= 224400003
I/flutter (10681): Android 7.0 (SDK 24), HUAWEI EVA-L19
I/art     (10681): Do full code cache collection, code=101KB, data=123KB
I/art     (10681): After code cache collection, code=97KB, data=83KB
```